# In Nodejs Sequelize v6.6.5, Removed field still appearing in the result

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a field 'description' in my table, now I have removed from sequelize.define() but still description field is appearing in result set.

Model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const profile = sequelize.define(
      "profile",
      {
        id: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          allowNull: false,
          primaryKey: true,
          validate: {
            notEmpty: true,
          },
        },
        name: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: false,
          validate: {
            notEmpty: true,
          },
        }
        // description: {
        //   type: DataTypes.STRING,
        //   allowNull: false,
        //   validate: {
        //     notEmpty: true,
        //   },
        // }
      },
      {
        createdAt: false,
        updatedAt: false,
        deletedAt: false,
        freezeTableName: true,
      }
    );
    return profile;
  };
```

Result:

```
[
    "questions": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Ali",
            "description": null
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Khan",
            "description": null
        }
    ]
]
```

I have tried a lot of ways but non of them worked.
An assistance will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please show a Sequelize query you use to get this result

Comment: And definitely Sequelize does not query fields that it is not aware of. Search for duplicated registration of `sequelize.define("profile"`